# ValueError: Layer "model_2" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors with tf-explain

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a CNN using an pneumonia x-ray dataset that follows this format:

```
 --test
      --NORMAL
      --PNEUMONIA
 --train
      --NORMAL
      --PNEUMONIA
```

Due to this file structure, I can eaisly split the data using [.flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_preprocessing.image.image_data_generator import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2

train = ImageDataGenerator (rescale = 1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator (rescale = 1/255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory ('/content/chestxray/train/', 
                                           target_size = (200,200), 
                                           batch_size = 3, 
                                           class_mode = 'binary', 
                                           color_mode='grayscale') 

validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory ('/content/chestxray/test/', 
                                                     target_size=(200,200), 
                                                     batch_size=3,
                                                     class_mode='binary',
                                                     color_mode='grayscale')
```

When I run this with tf-explain:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import optimizers
from tf_explain.callbacks.activations_visualization import ActivationsVisualizationCallback


model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu', #convolution layer
                                                         input_shape= (200,200,1)),
                                                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D (2,2),
                                  
                                  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D (32,(3,3),activation='relu'), 
                                  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D (2,2),
                                  
                                  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D (64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
                                  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D (2,2),

                                  tf.keras.layers.Flatten (),

                                  tf.keras.layers.Dense (512, activation='relu'),
                                  tf.keras.layers.Dense (1,activation ='sigmoid')
                                  
                                  ])

callbacks = [ActivationsVisualizationCallback(validation_data=validation_dataset, layers_name=["conv2d"], output_dir="/content",),]

model.compile (loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001),
               metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fit=model.fit(train_dataset,
                    steps_per_epoch = 3,
                    epochs = 20,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset,
                    callbacks=callbacks
                    )
```

This error it thrown:

```
   ValueError: Layer "model_2" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 200, 200, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>]
```

I know the reason for the error. I use .flow_from_directory so I do not have seperate into x_train, x_val, y_val, and y_train. In the [docuemntation](https://tf-explain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html), (x_val, y_val) are used for the validation parameter in callbacks instead of one combined validation_dataset:

```
callbacks = [
    GradientsInputsCallback(
        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        class_index=0,
        output_dir=output_dir,
    ),
]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_30 (Conv2D)          (None, 198, 198, 16)      160       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_30 (MaxPoolin  (None, 99, 99, 16)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_31 (Conv2D)          (None, 97, 97, 32)        4640      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_31 (MaxPoolin  (None, 48, 48, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_32 (Conv2D)          (None, 46, 46, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_32 (MaxPoolin  (None, 23, 23, 64)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_10 (Flatten)        (None, 33856)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_20 (Dense)            (None, 512)               17334784  
                                                                 
 dense_21 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 513       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 17,358,593
Trainable params: 17,358,593
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

EDIT:

```
training_x = []
training_y = []
validation_x = []
validation_y = []

fold1="/content/chestxray/train/NORMAL/"
for filename in os.listdir(fold1):
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg"): 
        image = cv2.imread (fold1+filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.resize(image, (1852, 1443))
        training_x.append (image)
        training_y.append (0)

fold2="/content/chestxray/train/PNEUMONIA/"
for filename in os.listdir(fold2):
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg"): 
        image = cv2.imread (fold2+filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.resize(image, (1852, 1443))
        training_x.append (image)
        training_y.append (1)

fold3="/content/chestxray/test/NORMAL/"
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg"): 
        image = cv2.imread (fold3+filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.resize(image, (1852, 1443))
        validation_x.append (image)
        validation_y.append (0)

fold4="/content/chestxray/test/PNEUMONIA/"
for filename in os.listdir(fold4):
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg"): 
        image = cv2.imread (fold4+filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.resize(image, (1852, 1443))
        validation_x.append (image)
        validation_y.append (1)
```

Comment: `flow_from_directory()` produces batches that are datasets that contain arrays `x` and `y` value that correspond with `input` and `labels` respectively.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how I would resolve the error in practice?

Comment: If you debug and put a breakpoint after `train_dataset` and `validation_dataset` are created, but before your `fit()` method, you can see the contents of your datasets. You'll then see there are (at least) two arrays, called `x` and `y`. These are your per-batch feature data and labels, or x and y data. This is useful when you want to make, for example, a confusion matrix or classification report after performing predictions on the test set, if you use `Dataset`.

Comment: It should be as simple as `val_x, val_y = validation_dataset.x, validation_dataset.y`, or just pass the direct reference to them.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Debug your code, the arrays are there, might not be that exact name...

Comment: I think it is supposed to be validation_dataset [0] and validation_dataset [1]. I still get the originial tensor error though.

Comment: model_fit=model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 3, epochs = 20, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), callbacks=callbacks). I changed the validation_data parameter to this, but now I get a new error:     ValueError: Layer "sequential_6" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 200, 200, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>]

Comment: `validation_data` could've just been left as the `validation_dataset`. That error means your datasets weren't created properly or the model wasn't defined to match the dataset. Tensors also aren't arrays/lists.

Comment: Does the model work without the custom callback?

Comment: It works without the callbacks paramter. Why does the model not work once I add that paramter?

Comment: Try without the `y` portion of validation data. So change it to `None` within the custom callback.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Is my layers_name correct?

Comment: Do you have to use `flow_from_directory()` (does all of the data fit in memory)? Can you update your question with the output of `model.summary()`? It could also be an issue with `Sequential` model, [have you tried using `Functional API`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)?

Comment: See my edits. I don't know how to do it without flow_from_directory () because my data is labeled based on what folder it is in (see file structure).

Comment: Ahh I just checked, each batch has these arrays: `.classes` and `.class_labels`, those are your `x` and `y` arrays.

Comment: val_x, val_y = validation_dataset.classes, validation_dataset.class_labels                                         Like this? It still says it has no attribute

Comment: To use arrays instead (which would probably help most) you have to resize all the images to be the same shape, then append them (as arrays) to an array. Then have another array representing your classes, as 0 and 1, for NORMAL and PNEUMONIA. Save them to your disk. Then you can load them and use them as input for your model without using `flow_from_directory()`. For example, the two arrays would look something like: `image_array.shape = (total_batch_size, 200, 200, 1)`, `labels.shape = (total_batch_size, 1)`.

Comment: How do I resize an image to a given size? Would doing ```image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)``` take care of it? And just iterate through the folder?

Comment: `cv2.resize(img, shape)`, where `img` is the image and `shape` is the desired shape, then store the resized image in the images array, along with the corresponding label. You'll need a loop, of course, to go through every picture. Then save at the end.

Comment: See my edit. Is this the correct approach? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, that's outside the scope of the question. I would try to look up how to save/load arrays or debug and look into your validation dataset.

Comment: But yes, that's right path.